# Basic a tiff processing with photoshop using python

Tags: python, image, save, photoshop, tiff

I need to write a script that does the following:

```
# open a tiff
# get it's dpi, width, height and colorspace
# set the dpi, width, height and colorspace
# and then save the tiff out with no compression and no layers.
```

So far I've gotten:

```
from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch
ps = Dispatch( "Photoshop.Application" )

file_path = "C:\\Users\\me\\myImg.tif"
doc = ps.Open( file_path )

dpi     = doc.Resolution
width   = doc.Width             # in cm
height  = doc.Height            # in cm

# up to here the code works, but then I try
doc.Resolution = 72
ps.ResizeImage( 120 , 120 )
ps.PsColorSpaceType( 3 ) # psSRGB

ps.TiffSaveOptions.ImageCompression = 1 # psNoTIFFCompression
ps.TiffSaveOptions.Layers = False
ps.Save()

# and this last section fails
```

Please help, any ideas, tips, soultions would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: Can you provide the output where it 'bombs'? Nobody knows what that means. Out of curiosity, are you able to use PIL or are your bound to photoshop?

Comment: Bombs means fails/errors out, sorry. I've tried PIL and it can't even read the tiff's correctly. In a few forums people recommend trying a variation of image processing modules/libraries etc but none of them seem to be 100% successful i.e there are always a few tiffs that each module just can't read. Photoshop however can open all the different kinds of tiffs and our studio has a spare photoshop license, this is why I chose to use photoshop. I've also tried ImageMagik but that doesn't work with a few of the tiffs either.

Comment: As regards to providing the output where it fails, the commands after the comment "# up to here the code works, but then I try
" are more examples of what I want the script to do than actual correct commands. They are bits and pieces I have put together to show what I am trying to achieve. I haven't worked with photoshop through python before so I really have no clue what to do here. Thanks for taking the time to read my question though :)

Comment: I dont actually see a python traceback though. Are there no actual errors and it quits suddenly for no reason?

Comment: First google search returned this package which specifically claims to handle problematic tifs: http://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely look into the package you suggested. But I would still like the python code for photoshop. The python tracebacks would be irrelevant because as I stated in the comment above, those commands are not "real" commands. They would not work in any other case. They are mere examples of what I wish to achieve. I'm not having a problem with photoshop or python or python for photoshop. I just want to know what the correct commands are...

Comment: Ah ok I get what you mean. Ya I wish I could offer an answer but I don't have a windows box to try this out on. However a google search is bringing up quite a lot of windows-based examples, along with a CS5 scripting guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of googeling and some trial and error and then even more trial and error I've managed to come up with the code below.

Hope this can help someone else.

## Code

```
file_path = "C:\\Users\\me\\myImg.tif"
color_settings = "North America General Purpose 2"


from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch

ps_app = Dispatch( "Photoshop.Application" )

# set photoshop to use pixels as dimensions
ps_app.Preferences.RulerUnits = 1               # 'for PsUnits --> 1 (psPixels)         
ps_app.Preferences.TypeUnits = 1                # 'for PsTypeUnits --> 1 (psPixels)

doc = ps_app.Open( file_path )                  # Open a file and store open file as doc
dpi     = doc.Resolution
width   = doc.Width         
height  = doc.Height            

cor_res = 1024

ps_app.ChangeColorSettings( color_settings )
doc.ResizeImage( cor_res , cor_res , 72 )


options = Dispatch('Photoshop.TiffSaveOptions')
options.ImageCompression = 1                    # ps_appNoTIFFCompression
options.Layers = False                          # no layers


doc.SaveAs( file_path , options )               # Save with specified options
doc.Close( 2 )                                  # psDoNotSaveChanges
```